# jQuery search class from a list of specified classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have div with 6 classes. I want to know if that div has either class one, two , three, or four and set that as the value of the select box. I only want to search for these 4 classes and don't care about the other classes in the div. I have the following. Is there a better way to write it.

```
<div class="four whatever something"></div>

<select>
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
    <option>four</option>
</select>

if ($('div').hasClass(one)) {
    $('select').val('one')
} else if ($('div').hasClass('two')) {
    $('select').val('two')
}
if ($('div').hasClass('three')) {
    $('select').val('three')
}
if ($('div').hasClass('four')) {
    $('select').val('four')
}
```

Comment: @flynfish no, the OP wants to set the selected value of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like that:

```
var classes = $('div').attr('class').split(/\s/);
for ( var i in classes )
        $('select').val(classes[i]);
```

Comment: WTF? No... (1) [don't use `for...in` to iterate over an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Example) (2) [`.val()` does not return a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/MsrzU/1/. It's not working. Class `two` should be selected for this example.

Comment: didnt mean to replicate the logic, just gave another option you could use.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a better way to write it. You'd probably like to know what that way is, though. `:)`

```
var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'],
    $div = $('#myDivId');

for (var i=0; i<classes.length; i++)
{
    if ($div.hasClass(classes[i]))
    {
        $('select').val(classes[i]);
        // break;
    }
}
```

The `break;` is commented out to make the looped version match your current code. However, if you meant to use `if...else if...else if...else if` instead of `if...if...if...if`, the `break` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works great. @Uzi solution seems to be more compact.

Comment: Ok - just so you're aware, though, that code has different semantics from yours.